# Replace blank with NA in R

Tags: r, data.table

Tried most of the solution given in SO. Below are the attemps i tried

```
  DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("", NA, x))]  
  DT <-data.table(lapply(DT, function(x){ x[x == ""] <- NA}))
  DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x =="",NA))]
  DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("", NA, x))]
```

But the entire datatable is converted to NA in all cells. I want to change all blank("") to NA in all columns.

It is a `data.table`. Not `data.frame`

Also the data is not read from a csv file-where i can mention the `na strings`

More inputs. 
The data is read from a hive query into data.table. When i give view command few cells are shown empty and few cells are shown `NA`

```
Col1 Col2  Col3
      1     NA
2     NA    NA
      10    ABC
```

To convert these blanks to NA(In actual data i have more than 100 cols) i tried these commands. Also when i take `unique(DT$Col1)` i get "" and 2.

Comment: Maybe `is.empty()`?

Comment: You need to provide some input data so we can reproduce this

Comment: have you tried this ```DT[DT == ""] <- NA``` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type of variable are we talking about? Numeric? Character?
A better formulated question makes it easier to give a better answer.

This could help:

```
DT[DT == ""] <- NA
```

Do not try so hard. R should be fun!

Comment: Thanks !! You are right i tried all wrong ways i guess. None worked for last couple of hours :(

Answer (score 3):

To replace in place, you can do, as you put in your attempts:

```
DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x=="", NA))]
```

**Example:**

```
DT <- data.table(v1=c("a", "", "b", "c"), v2=c("b", "n", "i", ""), v3=c("", "", "r", "t"))
#   v1 v2 v3
#1:  a  b   
#2:     n   
#3:  b  i  r
#4:  c     t
DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x=="", NA))]
DT
#     v1   v2   v3
#1:    a    b <NA>
#2: <NA>    n <NA>
#3:    b    i    r
#4:    c <NA>    t
```